# Excel - How to display a certain cell if cell x was returned from an IF(COUNTIF) statement?

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula that returns the lowest condition within a range of cells i.e. it will look for 'Critical' in the range of cells first and if it finds it, it will return the overall condition of that list of cells as 'Critical', if not it will then search for 'Poor' and so on. This is used to find the overall condition of an assembly of parts - if a single component is in poor condition and all the others are new, then the assembly should be classed as in poor condition.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Critical"),"Critical
"&"See component...",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Poor"),"Poor
"&"See component...",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Fair"),"Fair
"&"See component...",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Good"),"Good
"&"See component...",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"New"),"New
"&"See component...",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Unknown"),"Unknown
"&"See component..."))))))
```

The formula above works to do that fine. The problem is, I also want to display the component name/s that returned the lowest condition. So if say cell B4 was listed as "Critical", then that would have been the cell that ended the IF statement. I want to show the contents of F4 if B4 was the value that ended the IF statement. So my cell should say:

```
Critical
See component [component name goes here]
```

Does anyone know how I can do this? I have posted a link below to the working Excel file to help in laying things out. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Book2](http://www.filedropper.com/book2_3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is the `MATCH` and `INDEX` fields working together.

`MATCH` will return the row number, and `INDEX` will return the value.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Critical"),"Critical
"&"See component..."&INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("Critical",$B$2:$B$4,0)),IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Poor"),"Poor
"&"See component..."&INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("Poor",$B$2:$B$4,0)),IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Fair"),"Fair
"&"See component..."&INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("Fair",$B$2:$B$4,0)),IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Good"),"Good
"&"See component..."&INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("Good",$B$2:$B$4,0)),IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"New"),"New
"&"See component..."&INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("New",$B$2:$B$4,0)),IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Unknown"),"Unknown
"&"See component..."&INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("Unknown",$B$2:$B$4,0))))))))
```

You could use the same approach to avoid the clunky code - have an index number for each value and do a `MAX()` or `MIN()` on the index value then use `INDEX` and `MATCH` in the same manner to return the condition string instead of the nested  `IF`

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! Do you know how I would show all parts that have the lowest condition using this? At the moment it will return the first one that matched and it stops searching, but I need it to return both parts if they both have the lowest condition.

Comment: that's what my comment at the end was designed to address. provide a separate reference list with the string values and an integer rank value next to them. You can use a VLOOKUP or INDEX(MATCH())to determine the rank value for each item in the value list, then use MIN() to determine the lowest condition.

Comment: I don't suppose you might be able to show me a snippet by any chance? I have a hard time getting my head around the syntax of Excel formulae.

Comment: I misunderstood the second part - I suggest you post it as a separate question for someone to answer. There is a new formula in office 365 - `TEXTJOIN` that would be handy here. You could use `CONCATENATE` but it doesn't support ranges. This is really a separate question and worth asking.